# Make nginx responde with 200 on 503 with Kubernetes annotations

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I have the following kubernetes nginx annotation. My goal is to return a 200 whenever nginx returns a 503, so I have written the snippet you see below. However, when nginx returns 503 I still see the custom nginx 503 page. Would someone know what I am doing wrong?

```
 nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |-
    auth_request_set $auth_resp_jwt $jwt;
    auth_request_set $auth_resp_err $err;
    auth_request_set $auth_resp_failcount $failcount;
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
      location @error503 { return 200 }
```

Comment: Why would you return a 200 on a 503 ?

Comment: @ABWassim I just want to find out to do that and if it is possible. It is needed in the specific application I am building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
    if ($status == 503) {
      return 200;
    }
```

This snippet checks the status code and returns a 200 if it's 503.